# postgis create a new layer from the st_within query for points with another layer

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to create a layer that contains all of the businesses in Los Angeles proper. I have a shapefile for the polyon of the LA boundaries (shp_laboundaries) and I have a set of points in the la region for the businesses (tmp_coords). So I want to do a query where I can find all of the points that fall within this polygon. In fact I want to create a new layer from these points.

I was having trouble getting the st_within query to reference a separate layer in postgis. I was trying a few different queries, but hopefully someone can tell me the correct form.

```
select * from tmp_coords where st_within(tmp_coords.st_loc, public."shp_laboundary");
```

or

```
 select * from tmp_coords where st_within(st_loc, select geom from shp_laboundary);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your LA boundary data consists of 1 single polygon, it's easy:

SELECT a.* 
FROM tmp_coords AS a 
INNER JOIN shp_laboundary AS b
ON (St_Intersects(a.st_loc, b.geom))

You can safely use intersects, it's faster than within.
If you have multiple polygons you first have to merge them with ST_Collect

Comment: Great. Thanks for the tip on st_intersects() too. That is useful.